# Write in Solr during Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: solr, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm trying to deploy Solr Cloud into Kubernetes using StatefulSets. My problem is that if I'm writing into Solr during a rolling update of the statefulset I get errors when I reach the deployment of the solr cluster leader. With just reads I can deploy Solr Cloud without any problems - using the SolrCloudClient in java. I've already tried rebalancing the leader on the preStop Hook of the leader but I still get errors on the SolrCloudClient writes... Does anyone have any tips on how to do a rolling update of Solr Cloud without any errors even during writes? Thank you

Comment: _I still get errors on the SolrCloudClient writes_ what is the specific error you receive?

Comment: Usually the errors are about the client not being able to connect to the previous leader. I have read this https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/read-and-write-side-fault-tolerance.html and it seems a partial solution is to separate the data into multiple shards... but I would like to know if there are any strategies that we can follow other than retrying the erroneous requests